# Basic database connection template PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where we want to be able to read from a database and give the user a list of resources based on the criteria from a drop box (e.g. if you live in Alaska, you are given Alaska resources).  I'm familiar enough with basic programming constructs, but not PHP itself.  Is there a good, idiomatic tutorial for this anyone knows of; something more or less plug and play where the basics are commented nicely and I can change connection strings and build the actual database myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to recommend using PDO extension, there are alternatives, such as mysqli with plenty of examples.
I would recommend looking at the [PHP manual for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to get to grips with what it's doing. A quick google came up with [DB wrapper class](http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) which should be good enough to get you going. (I've not used it but it looks simple enough).

Comment: I knew this was going to get dinged by people who really didn't even read the questions.  I was looking for personal recommendations and no amount of research I could do would provide me with a good answer for out there actually works well and has been vetted by some people who know what they're doing.  thanks.